# Propositional formula for A, B, AC and BC

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic

I am struggling trying to get a propositional formula of the following truth table: A, B, AC, BC.

For A and B it's easy: A xor B. However, when you insert a new literal C...

I tried using Wolfram by inputting the truth table (A & ~B & ~C) || (~A & B & ~C) || (A & ~B & C) || (~A & B & C). However, the suggested minimal forms are wrong since they do not consider C.

Can someone help expressing this in propositional logic using logical connectives like **(A xor B) => C**? Thanks!

Comment: Which do you think is more likely:  Wolfram is wrong or C is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the expression:

```
(A & ~B & ~C) || (~A & B & ~C) ||

(A & ~B &  C) || (~A & B &  C)
```

Both lines are identical except for the negation of `C`, this means that **`C` is irrelevant**: the value for `C` doesn't change anything to the output of the function.

This is also the conclusion one draws from a truth table:

```
|A|B|C||F|
+-+-+-++-+
|F|F|F||F|
|F|F|T||F|
|F|T|F||T|
|F|T|T||T|
|T|F|F||F|
|T|F|T||F|
|T|T|F||F|
|T|T|T||F|
```

Here `F` being the outcome of the expression. If you for instance take the first line: `|F|F|F||F|` the result is false, which is the same for `|F|F|T||F|` (with `C` flipped). By doing this for every (`A`,`B`) configuration one sees that the value of `C` doesn't matter.

Therefore you can simply exclude `C` from the formula resulting in:

```
(A & ~B) || (~A & B)
```

Which means **`A xor B`**.

[*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A%20%26%20~B%20%26%20~C%29%20||%20%28~A%20%26%20B%20%26%20~C%29%20||%20%28A%20%26%20~B%20%26%20C%29%20||%20%28~A%20%26%20B%20%26%20C%29) comes to the same conclusion (see ANF expression).

Answer (score 2):

You can perform minimization by means of using [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#Karnaugh_map) (amongst other methods - this one is the simpliest, you'll have to introduce a dummy variable D and just ignore it in the results).

The solutions are right about not considering `C`, though - it doesn't matter what the `C` evaluates to, as long as `A xor B` evaluates to true. I just did check that, to remind myself about how the Karnaugh maps are constructed. Try drawing yourself a full truth table to see that.

Comment: Thanks but Karnaugh map won't help either. I mean, as I posted, I already have the truth table: (A & ~B & ~C) || (~A & B & ~C) || (A & ~B & C) || (~A & B & C). I want to reduce it for this simple case in a simplified propositional formula (if possible using implication or equivalence. C is a new literal and has to be considered the same as A and B.

Comment: @user3907707: A Karnaugh card is a better tool for this as it visually shows which variables matter where. Furthermore you can syntactically see that `C` is irrelevant. Finally a truth table shows that for every combination `A` and `B` the outcome is the same for both `C` being true or false.

Comment: Thanks to you as well..sorry, if I did not understand your explanation about why 'C' is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer

**(A xor B) and (C => (A or B))**

Comment: Your expression is not minimal: it simply holds that each time `A xor B` is true, `C => (A or B)` will be true as well. You can safely cut the second part away here resulting in only `A xor B`.